# How to save Line-breaks in DB and display them in View with Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework

I have a Form with a textarea. When the Form is send off, the Datamapper enters the Data into the Database.

My Question now, how to I keep all the Line breaks to be saved in the Database?
In my view I use

```
 $this->escape($entry->description)'
```

I think escape() will filter this out won't it?
So I tried using the below

```
echo nl2br($entry->description)
```

I have copied some text with line breaks directly into the database, since I don't know how it is supposed to be saved, but nothing changed.

1. How do I save it in the Database? I just use $table->insert($data);
2. How do I than display the text with the line-breaks in my view?

I hope someone can help, because I can not find a solution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked fine for me with no problems:

```
$db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
$db->insert('testing', array('description' => "This is a test\nwith multiple\nlines in the db\n\nmore stuff"));

$select = $db->select()->from('testing');
$results = $select->query();
$row     = $results->fetch();

$this->view->description = $row['description'];

// in the view:

echo nl2br($this->description);
```

In the view I had my string printed out with multiple line breaks still in place.

The escape only calls [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) by default, which wouldn't effect the newlines.  But you will need to call nl2br because newlines won't cause the string to span multiple lines in the webpage, that is why you use nl2br.

So even when you manually inserted data with line breaks into the DB, you cannot get the line breaks when you select the data from the table?

Comment: Thank you very much. I just copied your text in my DB but i get it straight printed out with the \n, so no Line Break shows up.

Comment: Yeah if you can see the `\n` in the DB then it wasn't inserted with newlines, but rather a literal `\` and `n`.  The `\n` in PHP is transformed to a newline which is why it works with the insert.

Comment: If you just copy that code into a test controller and view, do you see the newlines?  You will have to adjust the insert to contain the minimal amount of data necessary to insert into your table.

Comment: Great, I entered it into the Controller and you are correct, it now works. So that means I will have to find a way to save it into the Database in the correct way and than read it out with nl2br. Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: I do understand now what happened. I had only words in the db and than copied long text manually into the db, so as you decribe, that won't work. Thanks so much again !!